# New file not detected by check50

Tags: python, csv, file-io

Scourgify exercise: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/6/scourgify/

In this exercise we have a file with a list of students (dictionaries with two key/values: student, house). We need to clean the file and write a new one with three key/values: first name, last name, house.
With this code I do get a new file formated as asked, but I get this error though:

**:( scourgify.py creates new CSV file,
expected exit code 0, not 1**

In GitHub there is a file with the asked format, but check50 seems not to recognize it or find it.

Here my code:

```
import sys
import csv


def main():

    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        sys.exit("Too many command-line arguments")
    elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
        sys.exit("Too few command-line arguments")
    else:
        if sys.argv[1].endswith(".csv") and sys.argv[2].endswith(".csv"):
            before = sys.argv[1]
            after = sys.argv[2]
            write(before, after)
        else:
            sys.exit("Not CSV files")


def get_students(docu):
    try:
        list = []
        with open(docu, "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                newline = line.replace('"', '').strip()
                list.append(newline)
        newlist = []
        for alumn in list:
            last, first, house = alumn.split(",")
            student = {"last": last, "first": first.strip(), "house": house}
            newlist.append(student)
        return newlist
    except:
        sys.exit(f"Could not read {docu}")


def write(before, after):
    students = get_students(before)
    with open(after, "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ["first", "last", "house"])
        writer.writeheader()
        for student in students:
            writer.writerow({"first": student["first"], "last": student["last"], "house": student["house"]})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what "exercise"? You could add link or some description.

Comment: first time I see `exit` with text - usually it used as `sys.exit(1)` to have exit code `1` instead of `0`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.